# How to get hardcoded information from an iPA binary

Tags: ios

I tried strings over application binary..but it is showing following error:
strings: object: malformed object (unknown load command 19)

Any other way to read hardcoded information from an iOS application's binary file

Answer (score 4):

1. The IPA file is not the binary. It's a ZIP archive which you have to extract in order to obtain the app bundle directory, in which resides the actual executable.
2. Even that executable isn't well-formed. It's encrypted with the AppleID of the user who has downloaded it. You need to decrypt it before being able to run `strings` on it (you can use some popular iOS application cracking tools for this purpose).

Comment: Strings command worked. But in output, It's showing hardcoded strings, selector names , code signing details and app's other details . I need to extract hardcoded strings only but output pattern is diff for every app. I am not able to find a way to extract strings part only from that output. Any way to extract string part? Any other way to read hardcoded information from an iOS application's binary file

Comment: @tina I've just shown a way. If you don't need selector names: too bad.

Answer (score 3):

To get hard coded Strings from ipa follow below steps :

- Get Clutch from [here](https://github.com/KJCracks/Clutch/releases).
- Decrypt the app using Clutch (`Clutch <ipaToDecrypt>`)
- Unzip the decrypted ipa, and get the app bundle directory.
- Locate the executable within it, and run strings command against the binary. 
  (`strings <app-binary>`)

Comment: When I run Clutch i get a /Payload folder containing the .app file and a folder called var, which has containers/Bundle/Application/<App name>.app in it. Is that right? 
In a video I have seen that there is normally just that .app folder in /Payload

Comment: You can find the decrypted version of the ipa under /var/tmp/clutch.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I had a particular issue where I was trying to find the hard-coded strings in an app for which Bitcode was enabled and I'd built an archive for exporting to the AppStore.
The final .ipa file unzips as usual, containing the binary at Payload/appname.app/appname, but `strings` and similar tools are not able to process this.
Instead I used the following commands:

`segedit Payload/appname.app/appname -extract __LLVM __bundle llvm.xar
xar -xf llvm.xar
llvm-dis 1`

You'll need to install the llvm tools (e.g. brew install llvm) to get llvm-dis.
This produces a file called 1.ll which clearly contains the hard-coded strings I was looking for (along with quite readable pseudo-source). If there's nothing in 1.ll, see if there's files named 2, 3, 4 etc. and run `llvm-dis` on them.

However for an ipa that has actually been downloaded from the AppStore, you will unfortunately need to use a jailbroken device where you can run clutch etc.